# Return a matrix with `ifelse`

Tags: r, if-statement

I have two matrices:

```
mat <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)
mat2 <- matrix(1:2, 2, 3)
```

and a parameter

```
a <- 1
```

using `ifelse`, is it possible to return a matrix when `a` is a certain value?
the code that I am using, does not work. For example:

```
mat.new <- ifelse(a == 1, mat, mat2)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The length of the return is completely decided by `length(a == 1)`. See also the helpfile with `?ifelse`. Your code will only return a single value.

`ifelse` targets vector input / output. Even if you get the length correct, say: `ifelse(rep(TRUE, 6), mat, mat2)`, you get a vector rather than a matrix output. So an outer `matrix` call to reset dimension is necessary.

---

**Tip 1:**

For your example, looks like a simple `result <- if (a == 1) mat else mat2` is sufficient. No need to touch `ifelse`.

**Tip 2:**

It is not impossible to ask `ifelse` to return a matrix, but you have to protect it by a list (remember a list is a vector):

```
ifelse(TRUE, list(mat), list(mat2))
```

But, this is inconvenient.

Comment: @zx8754 
Tip2, it actually worked perfectly. 
the problem I exemplified is a (very) simplified version of what I have in hands. I need to choose one matrix from a set of 5, depending on the "a" value. 

Hence Tip2, thumbs up

Comment: @Rui Then I would keep all mats in a list, and access as `myList <- list(mat, mat2, mat3, etc); mat.new <- myList[[a]]`