# Strange output of ifelse in R- single numeric value instead of list

Tags: r, list, if-statement

While writing a function, I need to write the following:

```
x<-rnorm(10)
y<-ifelse(mean(x)>=0,rexp(10,1/mean(x)),-rexp(10,-1/mean(x)))
```

Like x, I expect y to be a vector with length 10, but surprisingly it only outputs a single numeric value. Reproducible example as follows.

```
set.seed(10)
x<-rnorm(10)
y<-ifelse(mean(x)>=0,rexp(10,1/mean(x)),-rexp(10,-1/mean(x)))

> x
 [1]  0.01874617 -0.18425254 -1.37133055 -0.59916772  0.29454513  0.38979430
 [7] -1.20807618 -0.36367602 -1.62667268 -0.25647839

y<-ifelse(mean(x)>=0,rexp(10,1/mean(x)),-rexp(10,-1/mean(x)))

> y
[1] -0.2092798
```

What am I missing here? why is y not a list with length 10, even when specified in the condition?

Interestingly, when I encoded the same condition with separate if-else blocks, and it works as expected. But why doesn't the same logic work when executed in this way? some clarification would surely help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it being a dupe. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` can only return one value. Try with a common `if else` statement instead:

`if(mean(x)>=0) y <- rexp(10,1/mean(x)) else y <- -rexp(10,-1/mean(x))`

Comment: Thanks, and that's what I did in the end, just wanted to know if it could be done using ifelse as well. So one can't use ifelse if list output is required?

Comment: Got it, thanks. One should just make the output as list(). Will add the answer, taking a clue from dupe.

Comment: With clue from this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340081/return-a-matrix-with-ifelse

If one just adds list() for the outputs, it works as expected, i.e.

y<-ifelse(condition, list(output1), list(output2)).