# Return vector of length n to test of length 1, (or different shape from test) with vectorised ifelse?

Tags: r, if-statement

Is there a vectorised mechanism to return a vector of a different shape to the test object in R's `ifelse(test, yes, no)` function?

[The function is designed to return objects of the same shape as the test object:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449232/2706826)

```
> ifelse(TRUE, c(1, 3), 7)
[1] 1
```

But even if we get sneaky and try assigning objects so single length names are input, the result is the same:

```
> x <- c(1,3)
> ifelse(TRUE, x, 7)
[1] 1
```

The clunky control structure works:

```
> if(TRUE){c(1,3)}else{7}
[1] 1 3
```

But is there a vectorised way to achieve this?

[*Edit: This is asking a different question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340081/return-a-matrix-with-ifelse) asking about inputting matrices, whereas this is asking about inputting vectors, even if the answer turns out to be similar.* ]

Comment: taking from SO answer below... you could wrap the vector with `list`, i.e `list(c(1,3))`. But as the post mentions, this is clunky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340081/return-a-matrix-with-ifelse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) if** Normally one would just use a plain `if` in this case:

```
out <- if (TRUE) c(1, 3) else 7
out
## [1] 1 3
```

**2) replace** Another construct to consider is:

```
replace(c(1, 3), !TRUE, 7)
## [1] 1 3
```

**3) ifelse / list** If you really want to use `ifelse` this works:

```
ifelse(TRUE, list(c(1, 3)), list(7))[[1]]
## [1] 1 3
```